# How to use if statement in export default function in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain how to use if statement inside a functional component?

I am trying to define a constant based on the value of an event being passed into props.

For instance,

```
export default function Event({ evt }) {

//const newVar = if{...} else{...}

//if evt.name is null, set name === 'Not defined"
//else, use evt.name.


return (
       ...my code here that uses newVar
 );
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are no differences between `function` and `export default function`. The `export default` keyword will just export it as a default element from the file to use in the other files as needed.

Comment: `const evtName = evt?.name ?? 'Not defined'` , then use `evtName` down below?

Comment: use ternary operator const newVar= condition ? trueValue : falsevalue;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong code, try the next example

```js
    evt.name = evt.name ? evt.name : 'Not defined'
```

if evt.name has a value use the value if not has value user 'not defined' as a default value

Other method to resolve your problem

```js
export default function Event({ evt: { name = 'Not Defined' } }) {
 
return(...)
```

With this method you are destructuring the object 'evt' and added a default value in name property

Comment: This resolved my problem. Thanks so much!